# Running the program with out GUI

Tags: java, executable, exe, execution

I have a requirement in my project that I have to run external program with out GUI even if external program has GUI(like notepad.exe).This is possible in .NET. But my program is in java. I found out that java does not have this facility.

Please let me know is there any program like [hstart](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/hstart.html)(which only hides the console not GUI) which hides the GUI if program is given as parameter(Ex: [hstart] notepad.exe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same idea as previous answer, but you can call through a vbs script.
For example, you have "run_and_hide.vbs"

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Return=WshShell.Run(Wscript.Arguments(0),0,false)
```

Then execute the script from java code and pass the target program in the first argument:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start run_and_hide.vbs " + "\"notepad\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to do that in .NET write a little program for this yourself and call it from your java app.

Comment: But then I need to have .net installed.